# Обьект формы для FormData

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с неудобной проблемой.

```
data: new FormData($('form')[0])
```

работает отлично, но:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {

  sendData($(this));
  e.preventDefault();

});

function sendData(submitForm) {

   ...

   data: new FormData(submitForm)
```

не работает. Я не могу понять почему. Я проверил и убедился что submitForm заполнен данными формы и информацией о ней. Тогда что тут именно не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Может быть так сработает - `data: new FormData(submitForm)[0]`? Сделайте сниппет, демонстрирующий проблему

Comment: @Darth Похоже `data: new FormData(submitForm[0])` работает. Но почему так?

Comment: а хз, вы же сами в первом примере написали - `new FormData($('form')[0])` ... я с jQuery не работал уже очень давно

Comment: @Darth До этого я делал [0] что бы указать номер формы на странице. Теперь же у меня форм может быть много, а обрабатываю я их все так же 1-м скриптом. Потому мне нужно либо вычислять index формы на странице, либо передать обьект отправленой формы. Но почему-то все так же нужно передавать [0] при этом. Очевидно я тоже не понимаю чего-то... (полагаю что для формирования обьекта FormData нужно передать ему только какую-то часть реального обьекта формы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `$` возвращает объект jQuery, который всегда представляет набор DOM-элементов, конструктор `FormData` аргументом принимает DOM-элемент формы и не может напрямую работать с объектом jQuery.

Во втором случае квадратные скобки нужны также, как и в первом, для того, чтобы получить DOM-элементы из объекта jQuery, для правильно работы нужно записать так:

```
data: new FormData(submitForm[0])
```

Либо вы можете передавать в функцию `sendData` объект `this` без вызова `$`:

```
sendData(this);
```